# Extract Text from HTML div using Python and lxml

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm trying to get python to extract text from one spot of a website. I've identified the HTML div:

```
<div class="number">76</div>
```

which is in:

```
...div/div[1]/div/div[2]
```

I'm trying to use lxml to extract the '76' from that, but can't get a return out of it other than:
[]

Here's my code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
url = 'https://sleepiq.sleepnumber.com/#/#@1'
values = {'username': 'my@gmail.com',
          'password': 'mypassword'}

page = requests.get(url, data=values)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
hr = tree.xpath('//div[@class="number"]/text()')
print hr
```

Any suggestions? I feel this should be pretty easy, thanks in advance!

Update: the element I want is not contained in the `page.content` from `requests.get`

Updated Update: It looks like this is not logging me in to the page where the content I want is. It is only getting the login screen content.

Comment: Since not all HTML is valid XML and the web is not in short supply of badly formed HTML, you may consider [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead.

Comment: What you see rendered in the browser can differ significantly from what is returned by `requests`.  I just tested your page and `requests` doesn't return any of the visual components rendered in the browser.  For any Javascript-heavy pages, I recommend Selenium.

Comment: Also FWIW, in my experience lxml does fine with broken HTML.  If it's really a complete mess, definitely check out BeautifulSoup.  Lxml also has the ElementSoup class which is just the BeautifulSoup parser.  http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html

Comment: How would you recommend getting the data if using a Web Driver like Selenium? The text isn't selectable.

Comment: Be sure to hide your credentials. This is a public web page!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried printing your `page.content` to make sure your `requests.get` is retrieving the content you want? That is often where things break. And your empty list returned off the `xpath` search indicates "not found."

Assuming that's okay, your parsing is close. I just tried the following, which is successful:

```
from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring('<body><div class="number">76</div></body>')
number = tree.xpath('//div[@class="number"]/text()')[0]
```

`number` now equals `'76'`. Note the `[0]` indexing, because `xpath` always returns a list of what's found. You have to dereference to find the content.

A common gotcha here is that the XPath `text()` function isn't as inclusive or straightforward as it might seem. If there are any sub-elements to the `div`--e.g. if the text is really `<div class="number"><strong>76</strong></div>` then `text()` will return an empty list, because the text belongs to the `strong` not the `div`. In real-world HTML--especially HTML that's ever been cut-and-pasted from a word processor, or otherwise edited by humans--such extra elements are entirely common.

While it won't solve all known text management issues, one handy workaround is to use the `//` multi-level indirection instead of the `/` single-level indirection to text:

```
number = ''.join(tree.xpath('//div[@class="number"]//text()'))
```

Now, regardless of whether there are sub-elements or not, the total text will be concatenated and returned.

**Update** Ok, if your problem is logging in, you probably want to try a `requests.post` (rather than `.get`) at minimum. In simpler cases, just that change might work. In others, the login needs to be done to a separate page than the page you want to retrieve/scape. In that case, you probably want to use a session object:

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    # First POST to the login page
    landing_page = session.post(login_url, data=values)

    # Now make authenticated request within the session
    page = session.get(url)
    # ...use page as above...
```

This is a bit more complex, but shows the logic for a separate login page. Many sites (e.g. WordPress sites) require this. Post-authentication, they often take you to pages (like the site home page) that isn't interesting content (though it can be scraped to identify whether the login was successful). This altered login workflow doesn't change any of the parsing techniques, which work as above.

Comment: Actually, checking the page.content does not have the content I am looking for, so I'm not sure that doing a request will work, thanks for all the explanation though, sorry I didn't realize that earlier

Comment: So I realized the page.content is giving me the content for the login screen, not the page where the content I want is, so my requests.get(url, data=values) must not be doing something right...

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jonathan, I tried that setup but still am getting the login page content. If I inspect the site as it logs in, it's posting a login and requesting several cookies, but no response cookies. Is there a chance I'm missing something there? Looks like key, registration, and userId

Answer (score 2):

Beautiful Soup(http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup) will help u out.

another way
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

Answer (score 1):

I'd use plain regex over xml tools in this case. It's easier to handle.

```
import re
import requests

url = 'http://sleepiq.sleepnumber.com/#/user/-9223372029758346943#@2'
values = {'email-email': 'my@gmail.com', 'password-clear': 'Combination',
          'password-password': 'mypassword'}

page = requests.get(url, data=values, timeout=5)
m = re.search(r'(\w*)(<div class="number">)(.*)(<\/div>)', page.content)
# m = re.search(r'(\w*)(<title>)(.*)(<\/title>)', page.content)

if m:
    print(m.group(3))
else:
    print('Not found')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
This gives me:    
    TypeError: expected string or buffer.
Is there a different format I should use for tree?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry - you need to provide tree as a string, so it should be possible to just pass in page.text to it. Fixed the answer, pls check if it works for you.

Comment: in <module>    print(m.group(3)):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

It isn't finding anything in the re.search

Comment: That either means that page.text contains no text where the pattern fits or the response in page has no text. Try to print out page.text before. Can you give me the URL you're calling up?

Comment: i updated the question to have the URL with my login

Comment: The problem is, that in the response, there is no `<div class='number'>`, so the regex will have no matcher. I tried it with <title> and it worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102404/discussion-between-ferdy-and-mike).

Comment: For the love of God, no. Yes, you can do simple XML parsing with regexes. But it's a very fragile approach. If the `div` from which you want to extract data has any substructure (such as text styling spans e.g. `span`, `i`, `strong`, etc.) the regex approach simply won't work.

Comment: Ok, I think that's what I'm finding out because the request content doesn't have the element I'm looking for in it

Comment: When having `TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object` error in Python3 one might need to replace additionally decode page content i.e. use: `page.content.decode()` instead of plain `page.content`.